# How to persist an object instance across Angular controllers using a Service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm attempting to pass a "user model" instance across multiple controllers and directives inside of Angular. My model looks like this:

```
var userFactory = function (addressFactory) {
    var User = function () {
        BillingAddress = addressFactory.createAddress();
        ShippingAddress = addressFactory.createAddress();
        FirstName = '';
    }

    return {
        create: function(){return new User()}
    }
}


var userModel = function (userFactory) {

    var model = userFactory.create();

    return {
        model: model
    }
}
app.factory('addressFactory', ['securedHttp', 'utility', addressFactory]);
app.factory('userFactory', ['addressFactory', userFactory]);
```

userModel.model will be used to bind to Angular forms, including multiple controllers. I want changes in all controllers to reflect their changes back to this instance.

I want all services to be able to reference this userModel.model and get the latest changes that have been made to the model.

```
 var MyController1 = function ($scope, userModel) {
   $scope.user = userModel;
   userModel.model.FirstName = "blahblah";

}
   var MyDirectiveController2 = function ($scope, userModel) {
        //EXPECT:
        userModel.model.FirstName == "blahblah";
}

var myOtherService = function(userModel){
//EXPECT:
userModel.model.FirstName == "blahblah";
}
```

This isn't working. It is my understanding that services are singletons, but I am unable to alter data on the model and have that reflect across different contexts.

Any suggestions on the proper way to do this? I can share scope or pass the scope variable through to each controller, but that seems like a kinda messy way of passing a dependency that already exists as a service.

Comment: Please try to avoid self = this pattern whenever possible. In your case, you do not need to do that at all.

Comment: I've made some updates to remove the self=this pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused by your code. Are you trying to bind data to userFactory.billingAddress, etc or userModel.model?
One big problem is that you are setting self.model = userFactory.create() but userFactory.create is not returning anything. So basically, user.model will be undefined.

I do not know your exact use case, so cannot give the best solution. In most scenarios, user model will be responsible for just storing the user data, user factory will be responsible for just creating the user, and will generally be called from some controller/directive. An example would be, from login controller, I will call loginServive that will get user details on successful login from the backend api, and then store the user details in usermodel.

In your example, I won't call userFactory.create from usermodel. If you want to create the model from some other factory or controller, the create method would be called from that factory/controller. Or else, I would just initilaize the userModel in userFactory.

```
var userFactory = function (addressFactory, userModel) {
    var create = function () {
        userModel.model.BillingAddress = addressFactory.createAddress();
        userModel.model.ShippingAddress = addressFactory.createAddress();
        userModel.model.FirstName = '';
    }

    // if you want to expose create method to public
    return {
        create: create
    }
}

var userModel = function () {
    var model = {
      BillingAddress: {},
      ShippingAddress: {},
      FirstName = ""
    };

    return {
        model: model
    }
}

app.factory('userFactory', ['addressFactory', 'userModel', userFactory]);
app.factory('userModel', [userModel]);
```

EDIT: I have created a plunker based on what you are trying to achieve in your code. See it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/rPglYXhHgXfs5ogSNhG3?p=preview). I have added a couple of controllers and injected userModel into them. I have also demonstrated how the data can be shared between the 2 controllers and setup 2-way binding so that the data is persisted. Hope that helps.

There were a couple of problems in your code-

1. In the function User, you will have to attach the address properties to this, otherwise it won't be attached to the created object. In your case, FirstName, etc will be attached to the window object, and not to the user instance.
2. You need to define userModel as a factory/service to be injected into another controller/service, etc, but I guess you already know that.
3. I still think userModel is not the place to create the model. If you want to create the model on app init, then just do it in userFactory and save it in userModel from there, as I showed in my code sample above.

Comment: Thanks Abhishek. There's an error in the pseudo code that I constructed for purposes of demonstrating my confusion. Unfortunately I only made things worse. The "create" method should return a new instance of the userModel, so it should read- "create : function(){return new create();} Again, there are additional issues, such as the incorrect casing and poor naming, but hopefully this helps illustrate further what I'm attempting to do

Comment: Hi, that's what my solution will let you do. User factory is the only place where user model will be created - that's its only responsibility. The only responsibility of UserModel is to persist user information. If you need to access user information from any part of the app, just inject UserModel to access that information.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, services are singletons, but your userFactory does not leverage a setter/getter for your model object.

```
var userFactory = function(addressFactory) {

    var model = null;
    var create = function() {
        var self = this;
        self.BillingAddress = addressFactory.createAddress();
        self.ShippingAddress = addressFactory.createAddress();
        self.FirstName = '';
    };

    var setModel = function(data) {
        model = data;
    };

    var getModel = function() {
        return model;
    };

    return {
        create : create,
        getModel : getModel,
        setModel : setModel
    }

}
```

Comment: How does exposing getters and setters in javascript in your example provide functionality any different than just exposing the model as a property? return { model: model}. Granted, if I want I can put more logic into it, but based on your example I'm curious if there's more than what I see initially.

Comment: You don't necessarily have to expose the setter/getter but that's the typical approach.  What is important is that when you call the create method the return value is set to a variable "model" in the singleton. Thus after the initial call you leverage the variable value stored in the singleton.